# How to edit the DefaultItem in the Kendo Editor Dropdown list . Want to display the inherited font-size which is 16 px instead of 'Select font-size'

Tags: angular, kendo-ui, kendo-editor

```
<kendo-toolbar-dropdownlist kendoEditorFormat></kendo-toolbar-dropdownlist>
<kendo-toolbar-dropdownlist kendoEditorFontSize></kendo-toolbar-dropdownlist>
<kendo-toolbar-dropdownlist kendoEditorFontFamily></kendo-toolbar-dropdownlist>
<kendo-editor-insert-table-button></kendo-editor-insert-table-button>
```

As per the documentation, the defaultitem can be applied in this way

```
<kendo-dropdownlist
        defaultItem="Select item..."
        [data]="listItems"
        [valuePrimitive]="true"
      >
</kendo-dropdownlist>
```

But there is no way to do this in the editor dropdowns. The only method I got close to is in JQuery which I am unable to implement in Angular. The link for that method is
https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/editor/configuration/messages.fontsize

I was only able to hardcode the values through CSS using the following classes:

```
:ng-deep .k-input {
    display: none;
  }
::ng-deep .k-select::before { 
    content: "16 px";
}
```

and I got stuck here with making the dropdown dynamic.

The following page can be useful to get the editor running
https://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/components/editor/tools/